# getting an error when deploying to railway

Tags: python, reactjs, node.js, express

i made some changes in a project that i'm current working, then after a merge to the develop branch it suddenly doesn't build anymore. I tried to revert the commit but the error persists.

Build Logs on Railway

```
╔══════════════ Nixpacks v1.19.0 ═════════════╗
║ setup      │ nodejs_14, yarn-1_x            ║
║─────────────────────────────────────────────║
║ install    │ yarn install --frozen-lockfile ║
║─────────────────────────────────────────────║
║ build      │ yarn run build                 ║
║─────────────────────────────────────────────║
║ start      │ yarn run start                 ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════╝
[...]

#8 35.99 Node.js configure: Found Python 3.11.5...

#8 35.99 Please use python3.10 or python3.9 or python3.8 or python3.7 or python3.6 or python3.5 or python2.7.
#8 36.75 error: builder for '/nix/store/hh8n2lf9hxvjrp2rgp6542acrcyg153i-nodejs-14.21.3.drv' failed with exit code 1
#8 36.79 error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/hr6azazr0rnipm5vda93z8fql7d6q20a-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d-env.drv' failed to build
#8 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c nix-env -if .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix && nix-collect-garbage -d" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
> [stage-0  4/10] RUN nix-env -if .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix && nix-collect-garbage -d:
35.55 Updating Autotools / GNU config script to a newer upstream version: ./deps/cares/config.sub
35.66 Updating Autotools / GNU config script to a newer upstream version: ./deps/cares/config.guess
35.67 configuring
35.78 fixing libtool script ./deps/cares/ltmain.sh
35.92 ./deps/cares/configure
35.95 configure flags: --prefix=/nix/store/mqrbjaaz590rl2fg527j7msg51igr6c2-nodejs-14.21.3 --shared-libuv --shared-libuv-libpath=/nix/store/hba5ja1cri7jd7gvw77dqxsvsccijhz8-libuv-1.46.0/lib --shared-openssl --shared-openssl-libpath=/nix/store/2fhqpp0hnv80hf66y1s72am8dahl1bq1-openssl-1.1.1w/lib --shared-zlib --shared-zlib-libpath=/nix/store/s5gzrzha72q79v92wqq61x9ir8xiwbxk-zlib-1.3/lib --with-intl=system-icu --without-dtrace
35.99 Node.js configure: Found Python 3.11.5...
35.99 Please use python3.10 or python3.9 or python3.8 or python3.7 or python3.6 or python3.5 or python2.7.
36.75 error: builder for '/nix/store/hh8n2lf9hxvjrp2rgp6542acrcyg153i-nodejs-14.21.3.drv' failed with exit code 1
36.79 error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/hr6azazr0rnipm5vda93z8fql7d6q20a-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d-env.drv' failed to build
------
Dockerfile:8
-------------------
6 |
7 |     COPY .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix
8 | >>> RUN nix-env -if .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix && nix-collect-garbage -d
-------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c nix-env -if .nixpacks/nixpkgs-bf744fe90419885eefced41b3e5ae442d732712d.nix && nix-collect-garbage -d" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
Error: Docker build failed
```

I rolled back the branch to the commit that build and deployed last time